# Can a psionic-but-no-manifesting creature use psionic powers? such as Elan with some Aegis class level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Can a psionic-but-no-manifesting creature use psionic powers? such as Elan with some Aegis class level. Normally not but there are some "tricks"
 Such Elan's trait the character gain "wild talent". As he choose to be Aegis "wild talent" become "psionic talent" ( described in Elan section). At this point he must spend 1 talent more for "Unlocked Talent" feat and gain ONE first lv psionic powers (described in  chapter 5 Ultimate psionics).... but if GM consider it appropriate  "psionic talent"="Unlocked Talent" (In campaigns where psionics is more common-place, it is recommended to remove the prerequisite of Wild Talent from Unlocked Talent and substitute the Unlocked Talent feat for Wild Talent to represent how the ability to manifest powers is common within the world.). It's all right? And then spend one more talent to gain "Access Psionic Talent"  and learn five 0 lv powers. Right? So which 0-level psionic powers can learn? ( are divided by class and Aegis in not present) and the same for 1-level psionic power.
Tx

Comment: I don't see any circumstance you provide that makes the previous question irrelevant, [Is Aegis a Manifesting psionic creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165461/is-aegis-a-manifesting-psionic-creature)

Comment: I don't know PF particularly, but normally I would expect to have some semblance of what is being asked. You might want to rethink the structure of your question abit (to make it less rambly, linebreaks are a good tool for this). However, if you are asking the same thing as the previous question, it is much better to edit that to include more detail.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Evidently this was meant as a follow-up to their [previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165461), and they were told to ask it as a separate question.  However it is very unclear what is being asked here.

Comment: You're correct, all of the information in this question is true, but you could have left comments on the answers KRyan and I provided on the question "is aegis a manifesting psionic creature?" if you felt the answers weren't accounting for information you knew about.

Comment: Yes, mikeQ Is correct. And Powerdork answers me completely. Only to know how many talents score a human 2hweapon fighter mutating to Elan Aegis.

Comment: Yes you can, but it will be useless sins aegis do not stack the eon effect of a creature when it hits a Kryan it does not add the status resistance of an element of magi.